# Is there a way to tame bats or ocelots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been doing an experiment of taming animals  which animals can and can not be tamed to follow and attack for you. Bats don't seem to respond to any type of food I use, and ocelots have hearts above them when I feed fish to them, but does not tame them. Is there a way to tame ocelots or bats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, there is a way of taming an ocelot, you would do this by feeding it raw fish.  You must be very careful when feeding the ocelot because it scares very easily.  When the ocelot becomes tamed it will change color, so you will know when it's tamed.

As for taming a bat I don't believe there is a way in vanilla Minecraft.  There are ways to catch a bat and place it in your house so it looks tame, but that would be for looks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can tame bats, but you should be able to tame ocelots with fish. [Reference the Minecraft Wiki for more information.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot#Taming)

Answer (score 0):

Ocelots used to be tamable. Once cats were put in the game, the Ocelots would turn into a breed of the cats in the game now but now they're both separate things.

Answer (score -2):

I know in normal minecraft you cane tame bats by giving them pumpkin pie, but I play minecraft demo and for some reason it does not work. I don't understand why.

As for ocelots, they can't be tamed but if you feed two ocelots fish that are next beside each other they will get a baby ocelot.